# Url rewriting of standalone php script in CAKEPHP application

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting

I've got a CAKEPHP app which has the following rewrite rules in the .htaccess in the webroot folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

I have never worked with CakePHP before and am a PHP beginner, and have written a standalone php script which I have in a folder named 'products' in the webroot folder. My index page in this folder takes in an id and then retrieves the product name and description from the DB. (There are hundreds of products)

So: www.domain.com/products/index.php?id=1

I wish to include a rule where by the URL should look like:
www.domain.com/products/the-flux-capacitor

Please can someone tell me how I can achieve this without destroying any of the CakePHP rewrites?

Comment: why dont you write that code in the cakephp application?? why do you need a php file in the webroot??

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't tried because I have never used Cake before and I don't want to risk touching the code in case it all goes crazy

Comment: seems to me that it would be less risky if you learn the basics of Cakephp and include your code in a controller inside cake.. :) and seems to me that it'll be easier. Cakephp is quite simple

Comment: `I don't want to risk touching the code in case it all goes crazy` - so back it up first then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the following URL structure `www.domain.com/products/the-flux-capacitor` you still need a way to map every product name, which must be unique, to its id, and it will be a larger effort.

However, if you use a slightly modified URL structure, `www.domain.com/products/the-flux-capacitor/id` (even Amazon does this), then it is much easier and the following .htaccess code will do the rewrite for you

```
#existing rules...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

#Insert new rule to match products, assumes ID is numeric
RewriteRule ^products/[^/]+/([0-9]+) products/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

#existing rules ...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. My id is alpha numeric, so should I use:  RewriteRule ^products/[^/]+/([A-z0-9]+) products/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]? Also, how will the rule know how to use 'the-flux-capacitor' in the URL?

Comment: If its alpha numeric use `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. I am assuming that your HTML already has links of the form `www.domain.com/products/the-flux-capacitor/id`, or that you will construct these in your application. The rule will merely map this link to your `index.php`, ignoring the product description and only extracting the id.